# Is it safe to delete .thunderbird after removing Thunderbird?

Tags: 14.04, thunderbird, memory-usage

I'm running 14.04 Server with a ~16 GB SSD and ran out of room.  I was able to clean up and get some free space but Thunderbird was using 1.7 GB in my home directory in `.thunderbird`.  I've uninstalled Thunderbird since it wasn't essential and ran various `apt-get` commands to clean up but the directory is still there.  Is it safe to just delete `.thunderbird`?

Comment: If I were you I would get a HD, backup my important files, install the Ubuntu OS in the SD and mount Home on the HD. 16GB doesn't sound to me like a propper space for a server (Taking in mind an Ubuntu install takes about 4GB).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most of the 1,7 GB will be emails and their corresponding attachments. Since you uninstalled it, one may assume you do not need the emails/passwords, attachments etc. anymore. If that is the case, yes, it is save to remove.

#### However

Be aware that emails you have in a POP account will possibly be lost. They will not be on the server any more unless you specifically set it in your `Thunderbird` preferences.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. If you have uninstalled it you can remove the preferences file.

All archived mail will be removed. As will all emails if you had a pop account. I assume that is what you want.

Comment: He will lose all the archived email in there. Right ?

Comment: @solsTiCe yes. But they will still be on the email server.

Comment: Where is + written that he used IMAP?

Comment: @A.B. He uninstalled it, that means he either doesn't need the emails or can access them elsewhere. If it's pop he wouldn't be able to

Comment: @Tim probably, but n00bs won't necessarily do what seems logical to someone who knows how computers work. Better to say "Assuming you don't want the archived mail, it's safe" or something.

Comment: @user3113723 there is no need to call anyone names.

Comment: @user3113723 he seems pretty proficient in Ubuntu...

Answer (score 1):

Also to free up some additional space you can try to run this command:

```
sudo apt-get autoremove --purge && sudo apt-get autoclean
```

It will remove all the dependencies not needed anymore along with their cached `.deb` packages that are usually kept in order to be able to reinstall them without having to redownload them; if you feel like you don't need to keep those cached `.deb` packages not even for the currently installed package you can also run:

```
sudo apt-get clean
```